# Asus laptop fans constantly on, Ubuntu 16

Tags: dual-boot, asus, fan

I've got an Asus ROG laptop and just managed to install Ubuntu 16 after a lot of struggle. But when I start using the computer (just opening firefox, nothing heavy at all) the fans start roaring at full power and keep on all the time. The laptop came preinstaled with Windows 10 and it did not have this issue there. Also, I am dual-booting.

What can I do to make the fan work as it should?

I have tried various solutions from several similar questions on here, but none have worked. Most of them did not seem to have worked for the original posters, either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the latest nvidia drivers and restarting made it work in the end. I also removed `acpi=off` from my boot parameters.